# Debugging selenium WebDriver code without starting the test from the beginning?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Let's say you have a selenium webdriver test that fails and needs to be updated, and it takes a while to get to the failing point. Every time you want to try new code, you'll have to run it from the beginning and wait. Is there any way to execute new WebDriver code without starting the test over from the beginning?

I know that with ruby and python, you can use an interactive shell to execute the code and see it live in the browser that webdriver launched. But is there any way to get something similar with C#?

My first thought is maybe to keep the browser window open and serialize the webdriver object so you can use it when you run the new code on its own test, but that's just a thought. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's **possible** to reuse previous webdriver session to start a new test(or webdriver instance). 
Basically it's to save and retrieve **sessionId** used internally in selenium.

Here is a post on how to implement in C# before v2.49.0
http://www.binaryclips.com/2016/03/selenium-webdriver-in-c-how-to-use.html

Since v2.49.0, sessionId is exposed in RemoteWebDriver (see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG), which makes it easier to implement session reuse!